# don't run PropertyChangedCallback in DependencyProperty

Tags: wpf

I created a `UserControl` with a `DependencyProperty`. I set a value for this `UserControl` on `FormLoad`. But when I run the application no value is shown.

My code:

```
  public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(PersianDateTime), typeof(UCDatePicker),
      new PropertyMetadata(PersianDateTime.Now, new PropertyChangedCallback((onchangedcallback))));

  public PersianDateTime Value
  {
      get { return (PersianDateTime)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
      set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
  }


  private static void onchangedcallback(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      UCDatePicker control = obj as UCDatePicker;
      PersianDateTime newdate = (PersianDateTime)e.NewValue;
      control.Years = ((PersianDateTime)e.NewValue).Year;
      control.Months = ((PersianDateTime)e.NewValue).Month;
      control.Days = ((PersianDateTime)e.NewValue).Day;
      control.Hours = ((PersianDateTime)e.NewValue).Hour;
      control.Minutes = ((PersianDateTime)e.NewValue).Minute;

  }
```

In my `FormLoad`:

```
uCDatePicker1.Value = PersianDateTime.Now;
```

when i use breakpoint ,`onchangedcallback` doesn't execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you don't change value,

Value is equal to `PersianDateTime.Now` before and after your assignment

onchangedcallback will be called only if you will assign different value to dependency property, you can change default value of dependency property to some default value if you want property changed event to be called at first assignment

If PersianDateTime is reference type(class for example) change your dependency property like this

```
 ...new PropertyMetadata(null,...
```

But looking on PersianDateTime type, seems it is struct so you can use

```
 ...new PropertyMetadata(DateTime.MinValue.ToPersianDateTime(),...
```

and it will work

Hope this helps

Comment: plz explain more.i set PersianDateTime.Now , but when run application show 0

Comment: is PersianDateTime your custom type? is it class or structure? show code of that?

Comment: it is a class , change datetime to persiandatetime.

Comment: why Sometimes it shows persiandatetime, but sometimes does not show ?

Comment: when set null, don't run application.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3888/discussion-between-arsenmkrt-and-user970404)

Comment: yes
'The invocation of the constructor on type 'UserControls.UCDatePicker' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception

Comment: Hey, do you find my answer helpful?